# MySQL UPDATE Resetting values randomly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a highscores table, it seems to be working fine apart from the problem of at random times it seems to be resetting certain users back to 0, this is my query:

```
$user   = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : "";
$time   = isset($_GET['time']) ? $_GET['time']  : "";
$videos  = isset($_GET['videos']) ? $_GET['videos'] : "";
$credits  = isset($_GET['credits']) ? $_GET['credits'] : "";


$user  = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$time  = mysql_real_escape_string($time);
$videos = mysql_real_escape_string($videos);
    $credits = mysql_real_escape_string($credits);
    $secret = mysql_real_escape_string($secret);

// Main Query
$retval = mysql_query("
     INSERT INTO
     highscores(Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
     VALUES
     ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     Time = '$time',
     Videos = '$videos',
     Credits = '$credits'
     ",
     $conn
     );
```

It updates fine most of the time, can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: What does each variable contain? Have you made sure each of them is set, and it's actually the database's fault?

Comment: What are the PRIMARY and UNIQUE keys of the table?

Comment: The way it is now, nobody can possibly see the problem. Provide a bit more context, and tell us what the values of those variables are.

Comment: Also, the way you're constructing your queries is asking for trouble of the SQL Injection kind...

Comment: Updated with more code, if you need anything else then just say.

Comment: @ypercube There is no `PRIMARY` key, the `UNIQUE` one is `Username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to update the credit and not zero it.

Say you set $credit to 0 before you execute the query, than the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE part will cause the current user credits to be zeroed. Instead you should do something like this:

```
<?php
$user = 109;
$time = time();
$videos = 'something';
$credits = 0;
$retval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO
                       highscores
                       (Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
                       VALUES
                       ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits')
                       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                       Time = '$time',
                       Videos = '$videos',
                       Credits = Credits + 1", $conn);
```

Comment: Alright thank you, is that the only thing which could be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO highscores(Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
    VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Time = Time + %2$s, Videos = Videos + %3$s, Credits = Credits + %4$s"     
    mysql_real_escape_string($user), // escape every variable you will be using in
    mysql_real_escape_string($time), // an SQL query to protect yourself against
    mysql_real_escape_string($videos), //  SQL injection or use parametriezed 
    mysql_real_escape_string($credits)); // queries with wrappers such as PDO or MySQLi

$retval = mysql_query($query,$conn);
```

If a user exists already, this will just add to the current `Credits` the new value, but it won't change anything else. This seems logical to me. If you also need to increment other columns such as `Videos`, do the same thing I did for the `Credits`.

Comment: What would be `%s` I want to update `Time` and `Videos` aswell though, `Time` is Time Ran, `Videos` is Videos Watched, `Credits` is Credits Gained.

Comment: @Jamie: Read about the [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function. It is a string formatting function. I have used it here, because it makes reading the query easier, by separating it from the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Other have pointed what causes this behaviour. Here's an alternative syntax for the `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

```
// Main Query
$retval = mysql_query("
     INSERT INTO highscores
       (Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
     VALUES
       ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       Time = Time + VALUES(Time),
       Videos = Videos + VALUES(Videos),
       Credits = Credits + VALUES(Credits)
     ",
     $conn
     );
```